# Android packageInfo signature

Tags: android, encryption, apk

Are there anyways I can learn what packageInfo.signatures[0] is so I can use it to apply the same algorithm in Python.

To further explain:

```
    private static SecretKeySpec a(Context context) {
        try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 64);
            if (!(packageInfo == null || packageInfo.signatures == null || packageInfo.signatures.length <= 0)) {
                return new SecretKeySpec(Arrays.copyOf(packageInfo.signatures[0].toByteArray(), 16), "AES");
            }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e2) {
            ThrowableExtension.a(e2);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This android app is sending some sort of a key that is changing based on timestamp with every request it is sending. And it is using the above code for creating a SecretKeySpec which then gets used in below.

```
    @NonNull
    private synchronized String d(String str) {
        byte[] digest;
        try {
            byte[] bytes = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
>>>>>>>     this.r.init(2, this.l);
            byte[] doFinal = this.r.doFinal(this.k);
            byte[] a2 = Bytes.a(doFinal, this.j, bytes, doFinal, this.n.a().getBytes("UTF-8"));
            digest = this.q.digest(a2);
            Arrays.fill(a2, 0);
            Arrays.fill(doFinal, 0);
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e2);
        }
        return jl.a(digest);
    }
```

So, I know that the function argument `str` is for some reason `currentTimeMillis * 1151` which gets used in `byte[] a2 = ...` line then gets hashed with sha1 there comes the time based changing part. What I can't find is what signatures[0] is in this context and how can I achieve it, in the construction of the class, `this.l` is assigned with SecretKeySpec ( signature[0] ). `this.r` is an AES Cipher. From the readings I made, I think the "2" in `init(2, this.l)` means decode mode.

And Can you please explain to me what is the effect of filling `a2` and `doFinal` variables with `0(zeroes)` in this context as it doesn't get used anywhere else.

Comment: AFAIK the `Signature.toByteArray()` contains the X.509 DER encoded signature certificate that was used for signing the app. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/61403954/150978. See also this code that reads the signature data to an X509 certificate: https://github.com/linchaolong/ApkToolPlus/blob/master/lib.JiaGu/src/com/linchaolong/apktoolplus/jiagu/utils/SignatureUtils.java#L49-L72

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this instance, `packageInfo.signatures` is the first signature that you find in the APK. Meaning, this is the first signature file that the Android system has read from the `META-INF/` folder inside the APK.

Basically, what you'll need to do is unzip the APK, look inside the `META-INF/` and grab whatever file has the extension `.RSA` (unlikely, but it could be `.DSA`). This essentially what the `packageInfo.signatures[0]` is returning, with the `.toByteArray()` making a `ByteArray` object of the data.

If you have any doubts, or are having issues further, I'd sugged using Frida to hook this function call and watch what is actually returned.